# Print PHP array of objects in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, object

The array below could return in various ways (with more or less elements):

```
array(4) { ["imagen"]=> string(11) "bánner.jpg" ["alt"]=> string(5) "muaka" ["destino"]=> string(7) "op_tipo" ["tipo"]=> string(13) "obj_connected" }

array(3) { ["imagen"]=> string(12) "Logo_RGB.jpg" ["alt"]=> string(7) "test123" ["destino"]=> string(11) "op_list_gen" }
```

Im saving this in a variable in PHP called: `$filtrosBanner;`. How can I get the values from this in jQuery?

I have saved the variable in jQuery as follows:

```
var opDestino = "<?php echo $filtrosBanner; ?>";
```

This returns an array but im not sure how to access each value individually.

Comment: jQuery uses Javascript syntax. If you want an PHP object to be read as a Javascript object, you have to encode it to a format accepted by it. Using `json_encode()` you could do that.

Comment: A simple approach would be convert PHP array to JSON and then use JSON.parse to access elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple approach for your task would be:

```
var opDestino = <?php echo json_encode($filtrosBanner); ?>;
```

This way you are converting an object (or array) from PHP to Javascript syntax.

Comment: Im getting unexpected identifier in console even though its showing this `var opDestino = "{"imagen":"Logo_RGB.jpg","alt":"test123","destino":"op_list_gen"}";`

Comment: Remove the double quotes and try again, please. (I will update the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `json_encode()`.  This should create a json object for your `var opDestino`.

Like so:

```
var opDestino = <?php echo json_encode($filtrosBanner); ?>;
```

Comment: Im getting unexpected identifier in console even though its showing this `var opDestino = "{"imagen":"Logo_RGB.jpg","alt":"test123","destino":"op_list_gen"}";`

Comment: Yes remove the quotes.  js expects a valid json string.  The quotes on the outside of the json encoded output violated the json formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Return the array with `json_encode` in PHP.

```
return json_encode($filtrosBanner);
```

In Javascript/jQuery use

```
var obj = JSON.parse(<?php echo $filtrosBanner?>);
```

To use this object , use it like this.

```
obj.propertyname
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implode your array as string using your PHP code and save it in a php variable as

**PHP**

```
$myarray=implode(',',$array);
```

Now take it in a variable in your script and then explode it using `,` to get your final array as

**JQUERY**

```
var myarray='<?php echo $myarray;?>';

var originalarray=myarray.split(',');
```

**Note:** but it will work for only indexed array, not associative array